# How to replace a part of a string using bash?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have strings coming in from the user that are of the form... `1,2,3` with any amount of numbers. What I want to do is replace the numbers with the corresponding values at the indeces of each of these numbers from an array. So say my array has [tom][jerry][sue]. I'd want my string to look like tom,jerry,sue when I'm doing processing it. Should I be using grep? bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string="1,2,3"
names=( nobody tom jerry sue )
indexes=( $(sed 's/,/ /g' <<< "$string") )
result=""
pad=""
for i in ${indexes[@]}
do
    result="$result$pad${names[$i]}"
    pad=","
done
echo "$result"
```

Explanation:

1. Simulate input string from user
2. Array of names, indexed from 0 (nobody) to 3 (sue)
3. Array of numbers generated from string by requesting `sed` to replace commas by blanks. There are other ways to do that, but I tend to use `sed` still.  For example, `indexes=( ${string//,/ }` will do the job without invoking `sed` or any external program.
4. The output goes in `result`.
5. I use `pad` to build up strings with a separator.
6. Loop over the numbers in the array `indexes`
7. Result is the concatenation of what was there before, the padding, and the name represented by the number in `$i`.
8. Set the pad to a comma for the second and subsequent iterations.
9. Echo the result.

I didn't count the 'do' or 'done' lines.

---

> I should've been more specific and asked you how the `sed` syntax works.

There are 4 interesting parts to the line:

```
indexes=( $(sed 's/,/ /g' <<< "$string") )
```

1. `indexes=( ... )`

   This is an array assignment.  It will take the words produce by whatever is in `...` and treat them as the elements of the array.  That's how the `names=( ... )` assignment works, of course.
2. `sed ... <<< "$string"`

   This runs the `sed` command with the value of `"$string"` as its standard input.  This is a `bash` extension called a [Here String](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings).  Thus the only line of input is "1,2,3".
3. `'s/,/ /g'` is a `sed` command that substitutes a space for every comma in the input.  Thus, the output is a line containing `1 2 3`.
4. `$( ... )` runs the command contained within the parentheses (the `sed` command) and treats the output as a string.

The overall effect is the same as:

```
indexes=( 1 2 3 )
```

The spaces around the parentheses aren't strictly necessary, but I think they make the array assignment easier to spot — but it is a notation I'm still 'learning' (having to remember to use).

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: I should've been more specific and asked you how the sed syntax works, but I can figure it out from what you've given me. Thanks.

Comment: No need for `sed` here: `indexes=( $(sed 's/,/ /g' <<< "$string") )` can be replaced with `IFS=, read -a indexes <<< "$string"`.